# How to show a View from a ViewModel and also set the data context of that view in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

How to open a new View(Dialog) from a view model command and also set the new view's data context with its view model. this question is bothering me a lot, although there has been so many question on this but I could not get satisfied with any of the answer so far.

So, suppose:

I have a start up dialog called MainView and I show this dialog and set its data context in App.xaml.cs (OnStartUp) method. In MainView, there is a button called "open a new dialog" and this button's command is bind with a delegate command in MainViewModel. So, when user hits this button, then command calls the execute method.
Let's say command in MainViewModel which is bind with button in view is as following

```
  public ICommand ShowNewDialogCommand
    {
       if(this._showNewDialogCommand == null)
        {
          this._showNewDialgoCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowDialogFromVM);
        }
    }
    private void ShowDialogFromVM()
    {
    }
```

And let's say the new dialog that I want to show is ListAllStudentsView and its ViewModel is StudentsViewModel. So, what are the various approaches of showing this dialog without breaching the MVVM pattern? And what are the merits and demerits of each approach?

Comment: I resolved this using `EventAggregator` pattern and having a WPF-specific `WindowManager` (a-la Caliburn.Micro) listening to the LifeCycle-based events of ViewModels (such as `Activate` and `DeActivate` and the like. Then the WindowManager creates the Window and sets the proper DataContext and DataTemplate, or closes the Window when the ViewModel becomes inactive.

Comment: Still, That was just *my* approach. I guess most MVVM Frameworks deal with that, each in it's own way.

Comment: HighCore,Could you suggest a link which explains the approach which you have used

Comment: This is definitely going to be highly dependent on your framework and overall design.

Comment: LordTakkera, I want a generalized approach which does not breach any piece of the MVVM approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to create a view (somewhere) with its datacontext set. Easy enough, we instantiate the view and either pass it the view model (assuming the view sets its data context in its constructor) or set it manually. The view could also have declared the view model in XAML if we so desired.

Method 1:

```
Window dialog = new ListAllStudentsView(new StudentsViewModel());
```

Method 2:

```
Window dialog = new ListAllStudentsView();
dialog.DataContext = new StudentsViewModel();
```

Method 3:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:StudentsViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Now we need to put this code (and the associated `dialog.ShowDialog()` somewhere). I see two options, right in the command's execute function, or in the view's code-behind (triggered by an event raised by the command's execute function like "RequestDialog").

I prefer the first, even though it doesn't adhere as rigidly to MVVM because it is a lot simpler, less code, and easier to manage. If you want to be very strict about adhering to MVVM however, I would have the ViewModel raise an event like "RequestDialog" in the command function that the view listens to and runs the constructor and ShowDialog() function.

Comment: Lord Takkera, I think MVVM mandates that we should not use the view object directly in view model

Comment: @Yogesh Joshi, Hence the event raising technique, by which the ViewModel has no reference or knowledge of views. I included the other method because, in my opinion, too strict adherence to any programming principle can cause problems, and this could be one of those cases.

Comment: Takkera, again when an event handler is bind with an event, then delegate contains a Target object property which keep strong reference to the object which is having event handler. So, even in event approach the view model would have view's object indirectly

Comment: True enough. Since you started in the view model, if you go down the tree far enough, the view model is going to have to talk to someone with knowledge of a view. The question becomes where are you willing to draw that line? You could definitely use a "WindowManager" class as HighCore suggested, or any one of a number of different approaches. I just gave the two (in my mind) simplest ways to get there without destroying the concept of MVVM.

Comment: As an aside, ViewModels ALWAYS have a reference to the view, because WPF is attaching pieces of the view to the PropertyChanged event. My point being, there is no magic in code. Eventually, hidden or not, the view model is going to have *some* sort of knowledge about the view.